# Sortable, filterable, user list in backbone marionette?

Tags: jquery, list, sorting, filter, marionette

See how nice and elegant this filtered list is:

http://kilianvalkhof.com/uploads/listfilter/#/united-kingdom/

Seems very simple.  Just need a simple unordered list and a little JQuery. Piece of cake right?  How do you do that with a collection in backbone marionette?

I have a marionette chat app and would like my userlist to look and function like that.  But when I say:

```
     var view = new UserListView({
                    collection: collConUsers
                });

     App.userListRegion.show(view);
```

I don't get a simple unordered list in my html output.  I can't seem to make one happen no matter the tagName or el combinations I try in my item and collection views.  Instead, I get output like this from my CollectionView:

```
    <div id="divusers">
        <div>
            <div>
                <li id="1">Rob Jones</li>
                <li></li>
            </div>
            <div>
                <li id="2">Steve Smith</li>
                <li></li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

A div wrapping each li and an extra li to boot for each user in the collection.

I get that backbone wants each view in its own element.  But how do I produce the effect above if I can't produce a simple unordered list like:

```
      <ul id="users">
            <li id="1">Rob Jones</a></li>
            <li id="2">Steve Smith</li>
      </ul>
```

Can't I make a list like that from my item view and collection view?

Looking around I see people complaining about the extra div's and li's.  Looking around I also see that filtering  and sorting backbone collections seems to be a nightmare.  There are so many posts on them.  I see Derek Bailey's collection level filtering proposal at:

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/183

http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/7tvzF/

I've got a few hours in and still can't make it work with my user list. And even if I did, it seems you have to type the whole name and leave the input field completely to get any filtering action.  I like the result at the link up top.  Smoother and more useful a keystroke at a time.  And seemingly not much code to it.  I'm just not wrapping my brain around how to achieve it in backbone marionette.  I have to be missing something simple.  Does anybody have a direction they can suggest here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some info that should get you to solve the issue:

- you can use a comparator (http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) to sort the collection by name
- you can use `tagName` etc to generate the HTML output you want, see this blog post: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/02/03/tutorial-nested-views-using-backbone-marionettes-compositeview/
- you can define a filtered collection as I did in [my book](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction), see here: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/entities/common.js (inspired by Derick's work you linked)

Then, you want to filter the collection (e.g.) on the input box's "change" event. Marionette will take care of redisplaying the filtered models. (See also https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_controller.js#L38 from the app developed in the book, with a live example [here](https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_controller.js#L38).)

Comment: Thanks for this.  Am reviewing carefully.  Looks like very good info.  On the comparator, I do have one and it seems to do a fine job sorting the collection but it's not sync'd with the UI.  When a new model is added the UI doesn't know about the sorted nature.  Looks like I have to do some sort of manual insert into the UI into the right place.  Not sure yet.  Let me review all of this and see where I stand.  Back in a bit.

Comment: You need to add a listener for the "add" event on the listener. In it, you need to manually trigger a "reset" event (with this.trigger("reset")), which will resort the collection in the UI

Comment: Wow.  This is deep.  So far some things are working though.  Comparator is sorting.  tagName, itemViewContainer, etc. have generated the simple unordered list I want.  Got stuck here though - https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/640. Model rendering twice in list when added. Not sure why. I'm just resetting after sort, not rendering.  If I comment out my add handler's "collection.trigger('reset')", I get the proper render, but no sort of course. Derick Bailey opened the issue a few months back and I don't think there is a fix yet.  Got to solve this before I can proceed.

Comment: Opened a separate question on duplicate model rendering by the CompositeView on add.  There's enough working here to go ahead and mark this question answered.  Anyone stuck on the duplicate model rendering issue can tune over to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142492/backbone-marionette-compositeview-sorted-list-renders-extra-model-on-add.  Thanks much.